# How to publish a single file using msbuild from command line

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

Does anybody know how to write a command line for msbuild that would publish one single file to the file system providing that i have that file? So i do not want to deploy on build or any of that. Just as if i would right click on the file and select publish from within Visual Studio.